# Do fake wasp nests actually fool wasps?

Tags: entomology, ethology

I have seen fake wasp nests sold as a deterrent against wasps and similar insects. Do they really work? Is there some scientific evidence for it?

A related link: http://www.scienceworld.ca/do-fake-wasp-nests-fool-wasps

Comment: I once heard someone who researches on wasps and he said that if you move the nest then the wasps get fooled and remain in the new location. I don't know about the fake wasp nests though.

Answer (score 7):

Wasps are **extremely territorial creatures**. They also have **great sight**. Wasp colonies will send out foragers and scouts to look for uninhabited areas with food in which they can build a nest. Because wasps are so fiercely territorial, a **scout wasp will generally stay away from an area with another colony already in it**.

Because of this fact fake wasps nest works!!

[image]

Source: http://www.environmentalsociety.ca/main/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/Fact-Sheet-Wasps.pdf

Comment: It appears your picture has gone down.